# Is there a Stack-Exchange indicator for Precise?

Tags: discussion

I'm new to Ask Ubuntu, and I am new to this Stack Exchange thing too.  I see that there are clients for Android and Mac.  Anything like this for Ubuntu?  Maybe an Indicator??

Thanks very much.

Comment: If there isn't it maybe an idea for someone participating in the Ubuntu App Showdown!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is, it's called [StackApplet](https://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-bringing-stack-exchange-notifications-to-your-desktop-1-6-alpha-f). There's a PPA and instructions for installing at that link.

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like this one doesn't need a PPA, it's just in the regular 'ol repos.

Comment: @DeanHowell: Yes, but the version in the "regular 'ol repos" is outdated. You'll need to use the PPA to run the latest stable version.